# non-static cannot be referenced in a static context/ graphic will not update

Tags: java, jbutton

I am really stuck on this. I know the other pieces work, but the buttons don't show the update on the graphic interface, and they cannot be static. Just hit a wall. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SlotMachinePanel extends JPanel{

private JPanel buttonPanel, newSlotsPanel, primary;
protected int tokens = 5;
protected int score = 0;
private String[] resultOfSpin = {"Winner", "Loser"};
public slotPane sPane = new slotPane();


public SlotMachinePanel(){

    newSlotsPanel = new JPanel();
    newSlotsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    newSlotsPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    JLabel slotLabel = new JLabel("Current Tokens: " + getTokens() + "  Result of Spin: " + sPane.getScore());
    newSlotsPanel.add(slotLabel);
    newSlotsPanel.add(sPane);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JButton spin = new JButton ("Spin!");
        spin.addActionListener (new spinButton());

        JButton cashOut = new JButton ("Cash Out");
        cashOut.addActionListener (new cashOutButton());

        JLabel label = new JLabel ("Spin to play!");

        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300, 40));
        setBackground (Color.WHITE);

    buttonPanel.add(spin);
    buttonPanel.add(cashOut);
    buttonPanel.add(label);

    primary = new JPanel();
    primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
    primary.setBackground(Color.RED);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    primary.add(newSlotsPanel);
    primary.add(buttonPanel);
    add(primary);
}

public int getTokens(){ return tokens; }

public void setTokens(int x){ tokens += x; }

public int getScore(){ return sPane.getScore(); }

public void setScore(int x){ sPane.setScore(x); }

public void spinSlot(){ sPane = new slotPane();}

public void spinPressed(){
    setTokens(-1);
    sPane.spin(); 
    setTokens(getScore()+sPane.getScore());
}

private class spinButton implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
     //this.setText("Spun!");
     spinPressed();         
     if(SlotMachinePanel.getTokens() <= 0){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Spun Out! \n You have " + SlotMachinePanel.getTokens() + " tokens!");
            System.exit(0);   
     }
  }
}

private class cashOutButton implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cashed Out! \n You get " + SlotMachinePanel.getTokens() + " tokens!");
     System.exit(0);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: That's a nice "wall of code" maybe you should narrow down the issue

Comment: @RC: This won't work since the scope changed, so the compiler would look for the method `getTokens()` in the `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ActionListener` of your `spinButton` you make a static call on `getTokens()`. You need to change that to `SlotMachinePanel.this.getTokens()`. This way you access the current instance of `SlotMachinePanel` in the `ActionListener`. The same goes for the ActionListener on `cashOutButton`.